# Response time of RTS and DTS pins of the chip FT232RL (USB to Serial)

Tags: usb, serial, python

I'm controlling the values ("High" or "Low") of RTS and DTR pins in FT232RL using python package [serial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html?highlight=setrts#serial.Serial.break_condition). My question is what's the maximum time between executing the command ser.setDTR(True) (for example) and the pin DTR actually reaching a "High" voltage (e.g. +5V). I came across the following documents, but I'm not sure how to get this information from them. From the docs, I'm guessing the response time is 16mS by default but not quite sure!

[Doc1](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf)
[Doc2](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN232B-04_DataLatencyFlow.pdf)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a definitive upper limit to the latency. The OS may delay running your process or running the FTDI driver or sending the USB packets randomly. If e.g. another USB device on the same bus consumes a lot of bandwidth, the FTDI packets may experience a long delay. If other CPU-intensive processes are running, your program might not even be scheduled quick enough. Python might decide to do some GC and block your program when you want to send your data. To get exact timing you need to use an RTOS anyways. In any case, 16ms sounds very optimistic.

Comment: Basically, an ordinary desktop OS (Windows, Linux without RT stuff) plus Python plus USB is the worst combination for real-time applications.

Comment: Thank you so much @Erlkoenig , your answer is very helpful!

Comment: No problem! You might be better off doing the time-critical stuff on a microcontroller that receives non-timing-critical data from the PC via USB or Serial.

Comment: @Erlkoenig could you post that first comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a definitive upper limit to the latency. The OS may delay running your process or running the FTDI driver or sending the USB packets randomly. If e.g. another USB device on the same bus consumes a lot of bandwidth, the FTDI packets may experience a long delay. If other CPU-intensive processes are running, your program might not even be scheduled quick enough. Python might decide to do some GC and block your program when you want to send your data. To get exact timing you need to use an RTOS and a different language anyways. In any case, 16ms sounds very optimistic.

Basically, an ordinary desktop OS (Windows, Linux without RT stuff) plus Python plus USB is probably the worst combination for real-time applications.